# Optimizing a function that projects a n-dimensional vector into a valid probability space

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, tensorflow

I have a python function that projects a list of probabilities into a valid probability space, with a minimum threshold `th` for each probability. For example, assuming `th=0.05`, input `[0.3, 0.3, 0.4]` returns the same list, while input `[1, 0, 1]` returns `[0.475, 0.05, 0.475]`. I need to use this code in `TensorFlow` and I'm trying to eliminate all loops and vectorize it as much as possible.

```
def projection(pi_in, th=0):
    pi = numpy.array(pi_in, dtype=np.float64)
    len_pi = len(pi_in)

    t = (1.0 - sum(pi)) / len_pi
    pi += t                   # sum(pi)=1, but values might be < th

    while True:
        n = 0
        excess = 0
        for i in range(len_pi):
            if pi[i] < th:    # fix values below th
                excess += th - pi[i]
                pi[i] = th
            elif pi[i] > th:  # count values above th
                n += 1

        if excess == 0:       # break when all values are valid
            break
        else:                 # otherwise decrement large values
            for i in range(len_pi):
                if pi[i] > th:
                    pi[i] -= excess / n

    return pi
```

This is an already semi-optimized version of the code. However, I'm having difficulties handling the conditionals in the code and the loop itself. How can I optimize this code to be efficient (as fast as possible), to avoid for-loops and conditionals (work vector-wise), remove the while-loop (this might not be possible), and be easily portable into the `TensorFlow` framework?